# Lambda variable is undefined. python

Tags: python-3.x

I get "subLambda is undefined" error for the code below.

note: sArr is previously defined as an array of numbers.

```
    subLambda[minimum] = lambda x : x - minimum
    sArr = map(subLambda, sArr)
```

Comment: Are you expecting `subLambda[minimum]` to be the name of your variable or are you trying to index the object `subLamda`? If the latter, you need to initialize `subLambda` first as an index-able object. If the former, brackets aren't allowed in variable names.

Comment: Also, having `sArr` already defined is inconsequential since you'll overwrite it with `sArr = ...`